# Regex matching group with variable leading and trailing characters

Tags: regex

There is a word template that is used to capture data from a user. The value provided needs to be extracted using regex. The section of the template looks like the following:

```
located in ________________ County
```

So when a user fills in the data, the output could have a variable number of _ leading and trailing characters. For example:

```
located in _______San Diego________ County

located in ________San Diego_______ County

located in _San Diego________ County

located in ________San Diego_____ County

located in San Diego County
```

The goal is to use regex to extract San Diego from any of the examples shown above.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What does your current regex look like?  Are you getting hung up in a particular spot?  Or just have no idea where to start?

Comment: It would probably help of you specify in which language or you neee to implement that (default regex syntax varies between programs/languages)

Comment: I have tried look ahead and look behind. Unfortunate, this doesn't work since the number of dashes will vary. I assume that I need to use matching group. But I have no idea where to start.
I'm not sure about the language. I'm using a tool that extracts data. And one of they way that it extracts the data is with regex. I'm not sure what the underlying language is. If I were to guess, I would say that the underlying language is C#

Answer (score 0):

`_+([^_]+)_+`

the matching group will match anything between any amount of `_`s

Comment: This will not work since there are other potions of the document that have the same pattern with _s. Also, the I want to exclude the _s in the extracted text

Comment: They would be excluded if you just extract the first matching group, as defined in `(``)`. If you tell me the language you're using I can tell you how to do it...
As alternative you could just trim() the _ from the result.


About false matches due to stray _ in the text... yeah, that's a problem. Probably a deal-breaker.

Comment: If I was doing this in code, it would be a lot simpler. This regular expression is something I have to provide to a tool that has a regex extraction feature.

Answer (score 0):

As a variant on Jay's answer. Using look-ahead and behind to not capture the `_` (finding more than one `_` being irrelevant information); and using a more exclusive capture group so that only alphanumeric, space, and tab characters are aloud. This will capture any text between `_` that are in the same sentence and line of text. If the input is a finite length, you can replace `+` with `{1,#}` where `#` is the length of the input.

`(?<=_)[A-Za-z0-9 \t]+(?=_)`

To improve the filter beyond that requires more knowledge of ways to tell stray groups from the valid groups.